# If over tightening wheel studs can cause them to wear/break, why do most mechanics use impact guns?

Tags: wheels, lug-nut, wheel-lugs

An impact gun seems to tighten a nut as far as it will go therefore I guess this is over tightening.

If over tightening can cause wheel studs to damage/break then why do most mechanics use impact guns and why do we rarely see wheels coming off?

Comment: The major cause of fastener failures is insufficient preload. That is ,they were not tightened enough .

Answer (score 2):

Most *mechanics* will only use an impact to take them off. They'll use a socket/wrench to put them back on, then a torque wrench to tighten them to spec. It's someone at a tire shop (without guidelines) who will use an impact gun to put the lug nuts back on. A good tire shop will *at least* use torque sticks to ensure the lugs are not over tightened when they use an impact gun. That gets them in the ballpark and then they torque it down the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by a combination of lack of training, laziness, ignorance & overconfidence. A properly trained auto "technician" would NEVER use a pneumatic impact gun to tighten ANY threaded fastener on a motor vehicle!

Comment: There are correct & incorrect ways to use tools. Use of a torque stick is common practice these days. You should withhold judgment since you have incomplete information.

Comment: Using non-English words is dysfunctional to this forum.

Comment: I was responding to your post. You had distorted my claim about auto technicians being improperly trained. You were trying to start an argument with me. I was NOT being judgemental. If you are a troll, you will get VERY frustrated with me.  :-)

Comment: Once again, you are showing your ignorance. There are torque sticks and torque wrenches. TWO DIFFERENT TOOLS! You desperately need more information.